# How can i wrap the text inside td with span

Tags: jquery

I have this

```
<tr><td>other</td><td>mytest</td></tr>
<tr><td>other</td><td>mytest</td></tr>
<tr><td>other</td><td>mytest</td></tr>
<tr><td>other</td><td>mytest</td></tr>
<tr><td>other</td><td>mytest</td></tr>
```

I want to replace the text inside last td with

`<span>mytest</span>`

I am trying this but i wraps the `td` not `text`

```
var r2 = new RegExp("mytest", 'i');

$(" tbody td").filter(function(){ 
        return $(this).text().replace(/\s/g, "").match(r2) }

    ).wrap('<span class="label-success"></span>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

```
var r2 = new RegExp("mytest", 'i');

$(" tbody td").filter(function(){ 
        return $(this).text().replace(/\s/g, "").match(r2) 
}).wrapInner('<span class="label-success"></span>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5swuJ/)

Comment: You can use a mix of mine and @SiGanteng answer like `$(" tbody td:last-child").wrapInner('<span class="label-success"></span>');`